# Xcode Code-singing/provisioning for test flight on taken over project

Tags: ios, xcode

I have taken over a project and am getting ready to build a release. How do you recommend i deal with the code signing dealio!?

Should i recreate/create new code signing identities and provisioning profiles?

What are the steps you would take?

I am trying to do an archive for a quick test flight release and its never compiling/archiving!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get new certificates and new provisioning profiles from your developer account. That way, you have control of everything.

For TestFlight, you need an Ad Hoc profile, and that profile needs to have the relevant device IDs in it.

You can find the device IDs of your TestFlight users in their info on the TestFlight site.